# Algorithm for simple string compression

Tags: algorithm, encoding, compression

I would like to find the shortest possible encoding for a string in the following form:

```
abbcccc = a2b4c
```

Comment: Isn't this *Start with a single `a`. Continue with twice as many repetitions of the next character. Stop at `c`.*? "The only information necessary" is "the stop character" for strings of up to 2**26 characters - barring the *decompressor/expander*: [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Informal_treatment).

Answer (score 0):

[NOTE: this greedy algorithm does not guarantee shortest solution]

By remembering all previous occurrences of a character it is straight forward to find the first occurrence of a repeating string (minimal end index including all repetitions = maximal remaining string after all repetitions) and replace it with a RLE (Python3 code):

```
def singleRLE_v1(s):
    occ = dict() # for each character remember all previous indices of occurrences
    for idx,c in enumerate(s):
        if not c in occ: occ[c] = []
        for c_occ in occ[c]:
            s_c = s[c_occ:idx]
            i = 1
            while s[idx+(i-1)*len(s_c) : idx+i*len(s_c)] == s_c:
                i += 1
            if i > 1:
                rle_pars = ('(',')') if len(s_c) > 1 else ('','')
                rle = ('%d'%i) + rle_pars[0] + s_c + rle_pars[1]
                s_RLE = s[:c_occ] + rle + s[idx+(i-1)*len(s_c):]
                return s_RLE
        occ[c].append(idx)

    return s # no repeating substring found
```

To make it robust for iterative application we have to exclude a few cases where a RLE may not be applied (e.g. '11' or '))'), also we have to make sure the RLE is not making the string longer (which can happen with a substring of two characters occurring twice as in 'abab'):

```
def singleRLE(s):
    "find first occurrence of a repeating substring and replace it with RLE"
    occ = dict() # for each character remember all previous indices of occurrences
    for idx,c in enumerate(s):
        if idx>0 and s[idx-1] in '0123456789': continue # no RLE for e.g. '11' or other parts of previous inserted RLE
        if c == ')': continue # no RLE for '))...)'

        if not c in occ: occ[c] = []
        for c_occ in occ[c]:
            s_c = s[c_occ:idx]
            i = 1
            while s[idx+(i-1)*len(s_c) : idx+i*len(s_c)] == s_c:
                i += 1
            if i > 1:
                print("found %d*'%s'" % (i,s_c))
                rle_pars = ('(',')') if len(s_c) > 1 else ('','')
                rle = ('%d'%i) + rle_pars[0] + s_c + rle_pars[1]
                if len(rle) <= i*len(s_c): # in case of a tie prefer RLE
                    s_RLE = s[:c_occ] + rle + s[idx+(i-1)*len(s_c):]
                    return s_RLE
        occ[c].append(idx)

    return s # no repeating substring found
```

Now we can safely call `singleRLE` on the previous output as long as we find a repeating string:

```
def iterativeRLE(s):
    s_RLE = singleRLE(s)
    while s != s_RLE:
        print(s_RLE)
        s, s_RLE = s_RLE, singleRLE(s_RLE)
    return s_RLE
```

With the above inserted `print` statements we get e.g. the following trace and result:

```
>>> iterativeRLE('xyabcdefdefabcdefdef')
found 2*'def'
xyabc2(def)abcdefdef
found 2*'def'
xyabc2(def)abc2(def)
found 2*'abc2(def)'
xy2(abc2(def))
'xy2(abc2(def))'
```

But this greedy algorithm fails for this input:

```
>>> iterativeRLE('abaaabaaabaa')
found 3*'a'
ab3abaaabaa
found 3*'a'
ab3ab3abaa
found 2*'b3a'
a2(b3a)baa
found 2*'a'
a2(b3a)b2a
'a2(b3a)b2a'
```

whereas one of the shortest solutions is `3(ab2a)`.

Comment: If you have a string say tctttttttttttcttttttttttctttttttttttct, then this code would return tc11tc10tc11tct which has length 15. However, there's a better encoding tc11tc2(t9tct) which has length 14.

Comment: @q85ts correct. see my note in this answer and my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since a greedy algorithm does not work, some search is necessary. Here is a depth first search with some pruning (if in a branch the first `idx0` characters of the string are not touched, to not try to find a repeating substring within these characters; also if replacing multiple occurrences of a substring do this for all consecutive occurrencies):

```
def isRLE(s):
    "is this a well nested RLE? (only well nested RLEs can be further nested)"
    nestCnt = 0
    for c in s:
        if c == '(':
            nestCnt += 1
        elif c == ')':
            if nestCnt == 0:
                return False
            nestCnt -= 1
    return nestCnt == 0

def singleRLE_gen(s,idx0=0):
    "find all occurrences of a repeating substring with first repetition not ending before index idx0 and replace each with RLE"
    print("looking for repeated substrings in '%s', first rep. not ending before index %d" % (s,idx0))
    occ = dict() # for each character remember all previous indices of occurrences
    for idx,c in enumerate(s):
        if idx>0 and s[idx-1] in '0123456789': continue # sub-RLE cannot start after number

        if not c in occ: occ[c] = []
        for c_occ in occ[c]:
            s_c = s[c_occ:idx]
            if not isRLE(s_c): continue # avoid RLEs for e.g. '))...)'
            if idx+len(s_c) < idx0: continue # pruning: this substring has been tried before
            if c_occ-len(s_c) >= 0 and s[c_occ-len(s_c):c_occ] == s_c: continue # pruning: always take all repetitions
            i = 1
            while s[idx+(i-1)*len(s_c) : idx+i*len(s_c)] == s_c:
                i += 1
            if i > 1:
                rle_pars = ('(',')') if len(s_c) > 1 else ('','')
                rle = ('%d'%i) + rle_pars[0] + s_c + rle_pars[1]
                if len(rle) <= i*len(s_c): # in case of a tie prefer RLE
                    s_RLE = s[:c_occ] + rle + s[idx+(i-1)*len(s_c):]
                    #print("  replacing %d*'%s' -> %s" % (i,s_c,s_RLE))
                    yield s_RLE,c_occ
        occ[c].append(idx)

def iterativeRLE_depthFirstSearch(s):
    shortestRLE = s
    candidatesRLE = [(s,0)]
    while len(candidatesRLE) > 0:
        candidateRLE,idx0 = candidatesRLE.pop(0)
        for rle,idx in singleRLE_gen(candidateRLE,idx0):
            if len(rle) <= len(shortestRLE):
                shortestRLE = rle
                print("new optimum: '%s'" % shortestRLE)
            candidatesRLE.append((rle,idx))
    return shortestRLE
```

Sample output:

```
>>> iterativeRLE_depthFirstSearch('tctttttttttttcttttttttttctttttttttttct')
looking for repeated substrings in 'tctttttttttttcttttttttttctttttttttttct', first rep. not ending before index 0
new optimum: 'tc11tcttttttttttctttttttttttct'
new optimum: '2(tctttttttttt)ctttttttttttct'
new optimum: 'tctttttttttttc2(ttttttttttct)'
looking for repeated substrings in 'tc11tcttttttttttctttttttttttct', first rep. not ending before index 2
new optimum: 'tc11tc10tctttttttttttct'
new optimum: 'tc11t2(ctttttttttt)tct'
new optimum: 'tc11tc2(ttttttttttct)'
looking for repeated substrings in 'tc5(tt)tcttttttttttctttttttttttct', first rep. not ending before index 2
...
new optimum: '2(tctttttttttt)c11tct'
...
new optimum: 'tc11tc10tc11tct'
...
new optimum: 'tc11t2(c10t)tct'
looking for repeated substrings in 'tc11tc2(ttttttttttct)', first rep. not ending before index 6
new optimum: 'tc11tc2(10tct)'
...    
new optimum: '2(tc10t)c11tct'
...    
'2(tc10t)c11tct'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is my C++ implementation to do it in-place with `O(n)` time complexity and `O(1)` space complexity.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int compress(vector<char>& chars) {
        int n = (int)chars.size();
        if(chars.empty()) return 0;
        int left = 0, right = 0, currCharIndx = left;
        while(right < n) {
            if(chars[currCharIndx] != chars[right]) {
                int len = right - currCharIndx;
                chars[left++] = chars[currCharIndx];
                if(len > 1) {
                    string freq = to_string(len);
                    for(int i = 0; i < (int)freq.length(); i++) {
                        chars[left++] = freq[i];
                    }
                }
                currCharIndx = right;
            }
            right++;
        }
        int len = right - currCharIndx;
        chars[left++] = chars[currCharIndx];
        if(len > 1) {
            string freq = to_string(len);
            for(int i = 0; i < freq.length(); i++) {
                chars[left++] = freq[i];
            }
        }
        return left;
    }
};
```

You need to keep track of three pointers - `right` is to iterate, `currCharIndx` is to keep track the first position of current character and `left` is to keep track the write position of the compressed string.